# Переадресация в зависимости от параметра

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Нужно сделать переадресацию по разным ссылкам. К примеру если телефон Iphone то на сайт Apple.com если Samsung то на samsung.com и так далее.

Итак:

Создал вьюшке с ссылкой, которая принимает модель

```
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstMVC.Models.Phone>
```

И в ней, есть ссылка по которой нужно осуществлять переход на сайт производителя.

```
<a asp-action="Info" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Сайт производителя</a>
```

метод для неё

```
public IActionResult Info()
{
    return RedirectPermanent($"https://www.apple.com");
}
```

в контроллере PhoneController.cs

Так же есть класс Phone.cs

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Телефон")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PhoneOnStock> PhoneOnStocks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Как логику реализовать что бы по ссылке (сайт производителя) которая есть у каждого наименования, каждый переход по своей ссылке.

По RedirectPermanent всё работает, переходил по ссылке, но как сделать для каждого свою не пойму.

Comment: Создайте свойство RedirectUrl и храните его в базе либо уж если хочется хардкод, то выбирайте в switch...case в зависимости от Name телефона. Ну и делайте `return RedirectPermanent(phone.RedirectUrl);` - только помните, что нужно сначала получить этот phone из базы.

Comment: @A K А, как можно получить phone из базы?

Comment: Если у вас база MS SQL то вы можете воспользоваться Entity Framework. Это отдельный вопрос и боюсь слишком большой. Почитайте для начала курс https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.1.php - а потом уже пробуйте осваивать и задавать более точечные вопросы.

Comment: @A K Я как раз и начал изучать MVC и это было в задании. В базу я добавил, как вы написали выше. Да так удобнее, не додумался! А, как из неё вытащить не пойму! Но в ответе вы подсказали, сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: В том онлайн-букваре как раз на примере телефонов объясняются выборке из базы почти весь курс. [Вот отсюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/4.2.php) почитайте про .FirstOrDefault, ,Find и прочие выборки.

Comment: @A K Как раз с помощью Find пробую! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы хотите в зависимости от того, какие у Phone данные - таки получить этот Phone из базы:

```
    public IActionResult Info(int phoneId)
    {
        var phone = this.GetPhoneById(phoneId);
        return RedirectPermanent(phone.RedirectUrl);
    }
```

Где получение из базы у вас будет сделано через Entity Framework, Dapper или вашу любимую ORM.

Я просто покажу, что возможно два варианта.

Во-первых, вы можете сохранить RedirectUrl прямо в базе и не хардкодить логику выбора этого Url:

```
    private Phone GetPhoneById(int phoneId)
    {
        return this.DbContext.Phones.Find(phoneId);
    }

public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...

    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
}
```

(По-хорошему, это нужно выносить в отдельный репозиторий)

Во-вторых, если очень хочется хардкод - ну так и пожалуйста:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...

    public string RedirectUrl  
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.Name.ToLower())
            {
                case "iphone":
                    return @"https://www.apple.com";
                case "samsung":
                    return @"https://www.samsung.com";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown product name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```